# Remove background from kinect depth data

Tags: background, kinect, depth

I want to remove background from kinect depth data. how can ı do that. Another way can ı change kinect max. distange range. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this function:

```
HRESULT NuiFusionDepthToDepthFloatFrame(
     const UINT16* pDepthImageData, 
     UINT depthImageDataWidth, UINT depthImageDataHeight,
     const NUI_FUSION_IMAGE_FRAME *pDepthFloatFrame, 
     FLOAT minDepthClip, FLOAT maxDepthClip, BOOL mirrorDepth)
```

`minDepthClip` and `maxDepthClip` can help you get rid of what you don't want by its depth. and also this function will change the depth data from `unsigned short` to `float`, from **mm** to **meter**.